# How to make lines invisible for displaying solely labels in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, labeling

I am creating a road map for the city. I would like to display only road names on labels. For this purpose, i have created a style. In this style, i have changed all of stroke-width's to 0 (zero) but it didn't work.

```
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          </CssParameter>
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `LineSymbolizer` from your style.